Want to know the BigQuery intraday end of the day time for set up a cron jon
I'm using the BigQuery as an attribution model. However, I'm facing some problems with lead details such as the original source.
Therefore, I've decided to set up a one-day cron job to update the lead details again or sync them in the CRM. However, I'm unable to figure out the BigQuery intraday 'end of the day' time to set up a cron job. How do I figure that out, and what is the exact time or how does it work?

Do you want this action on your GA4 table, right?

Yes, we've connected GA4 with BigQuery & use it for attribution. Syncing user details from BigQuery to CRM when lead is created. But BigQuery updates user details after some time. Which is failed to sync in the CRM so we tried, 1 hr cron job still facing the same issue.
Would it be better to sync the data after moving the information from the intraday table to the events table, or what would be the best approach to sync the fresh information?

OK, I answered it.

There are two ways to handle the creation of a GA4 table: one way is accurate and the other is based on historical data.
The accurate way involves creating a router sink that logs when a GA4 table is created using protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.jobcompleted" protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail="firebase-measurement@system.gserviceaccount.com". This log is then routed to pub/sub, which triggers a workflow or cloud function to take action.
The simpler but less accurate method involves finding the average creation time of your GA4 tables and setting a cron job to run at a time when you can be reasonably sure that these tables have been created. You can read more about this method here: https://medium.com/@aliiz/when-will-yesterdays-ga4-data-be-ready-bigquery-says-bye-bye-to-lag-b6e45aab36ca.

Thanks a lot @ali-izadi We will try it.
